# Textarea and Custom Scrollbar - jQuery custom content scroller

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I am trying to get this custom scrollbar plugin to work in a textarea. It works perfectly on the body, but I just cannot seem to get it working in a textarea.

http://manos.malihu.gr/

I did wrap the textarea in a div and loaded the scrollbar into it, but it doesn't show up.

Thanks for any help!

**I am making a wordpress theme.**

Here is the Textarea HTML and the script that loads the customscrollbar.

EDIT: `'<div class="comment-form-comment">
        <textarea required placeholder="Comment" id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>
        </div>';`

```
<script>
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("body, .comment-form-comment").mCustomScrollbar({

            autoHideScrollbar: "false",
            scrollInertia: 0,
            mouseWheel:{scrollAmount: 100}

        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The Trouble I am having is really how to just set it up. I googled around and cannot even figure that part out.

Comment: do you have a page or code to see. we can't really know what's wrong without any code.

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry I didn't post any before. I should have explained that I don't even really know how to set it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this [scrollbar comparison table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao4HbHsCLP0YdEhnZVh1WGZSbXloekZiNWlaNElnTnc&usp=sharing). Only 3 of most popular scrollbars support styling of textarea, and mCustomScrollbar is not among these ones. Try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) - it's fully CSS customizable and supports textarea scrollbars; or try [NiceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) (but it's not CSS customizable).

UPD. I was wrong. Malihu custom scrollbar supports textarea in version 2.8.3, but it was horrible. In new version 3.0.2 textarea support is better, but still not good enough: no scrolling on text selection with mouse/touchpad or with keyboard down selection; mousewheel does not work in FF over textarea

Comment: Thanks for the information! I try using your plugin (in wordpress), but I keep getting this error.

http://i.imgur.com/lTBAz3H.png

Comment: One of extensions, installed in your chrome, generates this error. As I can see, this extension's name is 'Hover Zoom' or something like this. It's not the JS error on the page.

Comment: Ah, yes I do have that extension. I also had another extensions I had to remove. What does this mean for me using the plugin then? If it causes errors with chrome extensions, I am nervous that other people will have the same plugins and it will break the site.

Is there a way to detect if it is working or not and if it isnt, disable it?

Thanks!

Comment: I think jQuery Scrollbar is not the reason of bug in console with your extensions. But if it is - it's bug in extension.

Comment: How can I fix this? I am sure other people use the same extensions. I guess I just cant use jQuery Scrollbar then =(?

Comment: @chap I have no idea. I don't use this extension. Try to ask someone you know who uses the same extensions as yours if they have errors in console. Or try to open jQuery Scrollbar demo page and look if error is still there.

Comment: I am not getting the error when going to the jQuery Scrollbar demo page. I have no idea why its happening when I plug it in then =|

Comment: unfortunatelly information is not enough to help you. Bug is not directly related to jQuery Scrollbar plugin as you don't have error on demo pages.

Comment: Ok, thanks for everything! I really appreciate it! I decided to just not use any styling scrollbar as most of them cause small issues such as the I-beam doesnt appear when hovering over text in FF. Thanks for the help tho :)